# Java spring JPA : Method 'PUT' is not supported

Tags: java, database, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have following problem. I just wanted to do a simple update request to my postgresql database.
But I always get following error code, if I try to test the request with Android Studio.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-06-21T03:30:21.661+00:00",
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "message": "Method 'PUT' is not supported.",
  "path": "/api/v1/products/3"
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
package com.mgg.flutterappbackend.products;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/products")
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Product> getProducts(){
        return productService.getProducts();
    }
    @PostMapping
    public void registerNewProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
        productService.addNewProduct(product);
    }
    @DeleteMapping(path = "{productId}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable("productId") Long productId){
        productService.deleteProduct(productId);
    }
    @PutMapping(path = "{productId}")
    public void updateStudent(
        @PathVariable("productId") Long productId,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam(required = false) double price,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String description,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String category,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String image
    )
    {
        productService.updateProduct(productId,title,price,description,category,image);
    }

}
```

My service

```
package com.mgg.flutterappbackend.products;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ProductService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addNewProduct(Product product) {
        Optional<Product> productByName = productRepository.findProductByName(product.getTitle());
        if (productByName.isPresent()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("product already listed");
        }
        productRepository.save(product);


    }

    public void deleteProduct(Long productId) {
        boolean exits = productRepository.existsById(productId);
        if (!exits){
            throw new IllegalStateException("product is not in the list" + productId);
        }
        productRepository.deleteById(productId);
    }
    @Transactional
    public void updateProduct(Long productId,String title, double price, String description, String category,String image ){
        Product product = productRepository.findById(productId)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalStateException(
                        "product with id " + productId + "does not exits"
                ));
        if (title != null  &&
                title.length() > 0 &&
                !Objects.equals(product.getTitle(),title)) {
            product.setTitle(title);
        }
        if (price == 0 &&
                !(product.getPrice()==price)) {
            product.setPrice(price);
        }
        if (description != null  &&
                description.length() > 0 &&
                !Objects.equals(product.getDescription(),description)) {
            product.setDescription(description);
        }
        if (category != null  &&
                category.length() > 0 &&
                !Objects.equals(product.getCategory(),category)) {
            product.setCategory(category);
        }
        if (image != null  &&
                image.length() > 0 &&
                !Objects.equals(product.getImage(),image)) {
            product.setImage(image);
        }


    }

}
```

And here is the request from Android Studio:

```
###
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/3?title=test
Content-Type: application/json
```

I'm expecting that the data on my database should be updated with the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Mapping path you are missing leading slash(`"/"`). So it should be like below:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{productId}")
public void updateStudent(
    @PathVariable("productId") Long productId,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String title,
    @RequestParam(required = false) double price,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String description,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String category,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String image
)
{
    productService.updateProduct(productId,title,price,description,category,image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the request is not being recognized as a PUT request, you can use this, just make sure that the URL is accessible :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/3
```

Or you can :

Change the @PutMapping annotation in your controller to @PatchMapping. This will map the HTTP PATCH method to your update method instead of PUT.

then modify request to use the PATCH method instead of PUT :

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/3
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "title": "test"
}
```